# WebSockets request was expected error when using --inspect-brk option

Tags: node.js, debugging, nodemon

When I run `nodemon dist/server/app.js` it works on default port `3000` and I'm able to reach my API. But if I run

```
nodemon --inspect-brk=localhost:3000 dist/server/app.js
```

I got error

```
WebSockets request was expected
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You can't run the debugger and your server on the same port.  Using `--inspect-brk=localhost:3000` tells it to run the debugger on port 3000 which is where your server already is.  Why are you passing a port number for `--inspect-brk` at all?

Comment: @jfriend00, I didn't run them at the same time, I tried to run debugger on the same port like the way I run my server without debugger. Because my client is using port 3000 to reach my server.

Comment: @jfriend00, I think I got what you meant, `--inspect-brk=localhost:3000` will try to attach debugger to the same port as the server is running. I didn't realize server and debugger are different process.

Comment: Yeah, the debugger is yet another server, built into the node.js runtime.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't run your web server and the debugger on the same port.  They are each separate servers (the debugger is a server built into the node.js runtime).

So, you can either remove the port and host designation from the `--inspect-brk` option and just let it use the defaults (which is all I ever use) or you can select a different port for the debugger that doesn't conflict with your web server or anything else running on that host.