# Why Node.js API not respond only in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
//...
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE');
    next();
});
//...
```

My local API on development server not respond only in Firefox. [Firefox image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6nYk.jpg)

But in Chrome, Edge and Postman everything works correctly. [Chrome image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBjlk.jpg)

Comment: can you show the client code

Comment: Are you by any chance running node debugger? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49766500/websockets-request-was-expected-error-when-using-inspect-brk-option

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you [Molda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3284355/molda).

Need to remove this:  `--inspect=5000`. ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGKDE.jpg))